# Command line formatting in LUA

Tags: lua, formatting

I'm getting stuck on the following. Probably pretty easy for you all, but I'm relatively new to LUA scripting.

```
return function ()
local getuservar = gma.user.getvar
local cmd = function(syntax, ...)
gma.cmd(syntax:format(...))
end
local Effect_Attribute = getuservar('Effect_Attribute')
local Effect_Group = getuservar('Effect_Group')
local Form = getuservar('Effect_Dim_Gr1')

cmd('copy image "B Form %s Active" at "B Effect Form %s %s" /m',Form, Effect_Attribute, Effect_Group)
end
```

That works perfectly.

What I would like to do is to create a string formatting for the getuservar, that looks something like:

```
local Effect_Attribute = getuservar('Effect_Attribute')
local Effect_Group = getuservar('Effect_Group')
local Form = getuservar('Effect_%s_%s', Effect_Attribute, Effect_Group)
```

How should I change the part of

```
local cmd = function(syntax, ...)
gma.cmd(syntax:format(...))
end
```

So, that I could use this style of formatting for my getuservar?

Comment: `getuservar(('Effect_%s_%s'):format(Effect_Attribute, Effect_Group))`